# Overlaying an image to a background image at specific coordinates on the background image? Python

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, opencv3.0, python-imaging-library

relatively new to python. I have specific coordinates on a background image which I would like to overlay an image onto. I am thinking of using the PIL.Image.Transform Affine transformation but I am unsure.

These are the coordinates on the background image:

```
box
Out[134]: 
array([[ 37., 119.],#TOP LEFT
       [615.,  65.],#TOP RIGHT
       [648., 416.],#BOTTOM RIGHT
       [ 70., 470.]], dtype=float32) #BOTTOM LEFT
```

Is there a way I can add a second image onto this image at the specific coordinates?

Cheers